# Visual Studio Code menu bar does not theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the [code 1.68.1-1](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/code/) package for Arch Linux. I am also running the plasma desktop.

All of the color settings in `settings.json` are working except for the Menu Bar (the one with File Edit Selection, etc). It remains white.

I installed [libdbusmenu-glib](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/libdbusmenu-glib/) as well but it did not help.

Does anyone know how to correct this?

My color settings:

```
workbench.colorCustomizations": 
    {
        "editor.background": "#21202e",
        "activityBar.background": "#21202E",
        "activityBar.border": "#000000",
        "activityBar.foreground": "#37ddcf",
        "activityBar.inactiveForeground": "#44465f",
        "menu.background": "#21202E",
        "menu.border": "#000000",
        "tab.hoverBackground": "#0f0e20",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#000000",
        "tab.inactiveBackground": "#18171f",
        "tab.activeForeground": "#FFFFFF",
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#282738",
        "titleBar.border": "#000000",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#21202E",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder": "#282e38",
        "sideBar.background": "#232334",
        "sideBar.border": "#000000",    
        
        "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#00ffb3",
        "gitDecoration.untrackedResourceForeground": "#f7aeae",
        "list.errorForeground": "#ff0000",
        "list.warningForeground": "#ff7221",

        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#EEEEEE",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#66ff00",
        "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000", 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to VSCode settings and search for "window.titleBarStyle" and set it to "custom"

[image]

Comment: This answer solved the problem for vs codium v1.73.1